# Does System.Xml.Linq.XDocument class implement IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq

I know you cannot run LINQ statements on objects that don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. I also know that you can run LINQ statements against an instance of XDocument class.

For instance I could do

```
    XDocument people = XDocument.Load(@"People.xml");

    var legalDrinkers = from x in people.Descendants("person")
                        where int.Parse(x.Attribute("Age").ToString()) > 21
                        select x;
```

But when I look at the metadata of XDocument and all the classes upstream in its inheritance hierarchy, I cannot see where `IEnumerable<Xdocument>` is implemented. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show an example of "can run LINQ statements against an instance of XDocument".

Comment: But the sample is not against `instance of XDocument` (+1 to Reed Copsey's answer) but rather a collection of nodes returned by methods...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use LINQ directly from XDocument, but rather off a method in it, such as [`XDocument.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) or [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) which do implement the required interfaces.

Comment: Technically, these would be the extension methods defined in the `Extensions` class in `System.Xml.Linq`, correct?

Comment: @Tim Nope - these are methods defined directly on `XDocument`/`XElement` via their base class (`XContainer`)